# SignalR GET requests 'Cancelled' when transport=ServerSentEvents

Tags: ajax, security, http, signalr

I have deployed a ASP.NET MVC 4 w/ SignalR application of mine which is working fine on all clients, except one. When using Chrome Dev tools to debug the page I see that the SignalR transport method is ServerSentEvents and that the SignalR GET requests have a status of 'Cancelled'. This is the case in both Chrome Latest & IE 9 Browsers.

This problem is specific to a single client. A few things I have tried are:

- Disabling Windows Firewall
- Adding my site to Trusted Sites with
  Security settings 'Low'.

As a bit of a background on the client.. they are part of a corporate network running Windows 7. Another computer on the same network had the same issue, however, this was fixed by adding my site to 'Trusted Sites'.

Answer (score 1):

AVG Internet Security was blocking these requests. Disabling 'Online Shield' meant the app returned to normal working order.